# Troubles with shebang in gitolite hooks

Tags: git, shell, gitolite

I have Ubuntu:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:        15.10
Codename:       wily
```

and gitolite:

```
gitolite3 3.6.3-1 (Debian) on git 2.5.0
```

I have follow lines in config file:

```
repo    livesearch
    option hook.post-receive = livesearch
    RW+         = @commonwrite
    R           = @commonread
```

and follow data in gitolite-admin/local/hooks/repo-specific/livesearch file:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/sh /var/lib/gitolite3/.gitolite/local/hooks/repo-specific/common seofilters
```

If I commit to livesearch repo with such a hook file, I get:

```
remote: hooks/post-receive: 18: hooks/post-receive: hooks/post-receive.h00-livesearch: not found
```

BUT!!! Just after I excluded shebang (#!/bin/sh) from the file, every think worked fine!!!

In both cases, I had on remote:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 git www-data   65 Apr 13 13:23 post-receive.h00-livesearch -> /var/lib/gitolite3/.gitolite/local/hooks/repo-specific/livesearch
```

and the link was fine!

More of it, I have other hooks, that works fine with shebang!
Just new hooks doesn't works with shebang, but I didn't update nothing...

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommended in the comments to try and compare the right and encoding or eol of the hooks which are working with the one which does not.
Maybe the problematic one had a CRLF after the shebang.

The OP confirms the EOL issue at the end of the shebang line.

Comment: But it done automatically by gitolite. I didn't touch it by my hand/

Comment: OK, can you try and update gitolite, in case it is a glitch with that version?

Comment: Also, try and compare the right and encoding or eol of the hooks which are working with the one which does not.

Comment: Maybe the problematic one had a CRLF after the shebang?

Comment: Can you answer my question, I will mark it as right answer?

Comment: @Olga I have rewritten the answer.

Comment: same issue, used notepad++ (edit->eol convention) to use proper eol for each version